# Can someone help me DRY up these jQuery each loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dry

```
function redundantSee() {

  var optionSet1 = $('.wrapper:eq(0)'),
      optionSet2 = $('.wrapper:eq(1)');

  optionSet1.find('.options').each(function(){
      var self = $(this),
          input = self.find('input'),
          title = self.find('.title').text(),
          value = input.val(),
          source = self.find('img').attr('src'),
          id = input.attr('id'),
          listItem = $('<li/>', {'value': value, 'id': id }),
          imageElement = $('<img/>', {'src': source, 'title': title});

      $('div.corresponding1').append(nameListItem);
      listItem.append(imageElement);
  });

  optionSet2.find('.options').each(function(){
      var self = $(this),
          input = self.find('input'),
          title = self.find('.title').text(),
          value = input.val(),
          source = self.find('img').attr('src'),
          id = input.attr('id'),
          listItem = $('<li/>', {'value': value, 'id': id }),
          imageElement = $('<img/>', {'src': source, 'title': title});

      $('div.corresponding2').append(listItem);
      listItem.append(imageElement);
  });
}
```

I've simplified this for posting, since there are going to be more than 4 options sets for this function to cycle through.

I'm having a problem figuring out how to turn all of the repetitive code into something much more manageable.

But since each option set has it's own each loop, the $(this) variable (and all corresponding variables) are specific to the loop that is run on the ('.options') element.

If I do one each loop and use a counter, like this:

```
$('wrapper').each(function(i){ // ... });
```

I still run into the problem of needing to redeclare all my new variables specific to that optionSet's turn in the loop.

Can someone help me figure out how I can condense this so that I'm not constantly repeating the same code every time I add a new option set to the function?

Edit:  The $('div.corresponding') elements are completely different for each one, so they can't be incremented with a counter.  (ex. One might be $('div.foo') or $('div.foo ul.bar')

Comment: This belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: _"If I do one each loop and use a counter...I still run into the problem of needing to redeclare all my new variables specific to that optionSet's turn in the loop"_ - Why is that? For the code you show, isn't the `'div.corresponding1'` bit the only difference in the two loops? And you could handle that with a counter.

Comment: You should create a function to be re-used. The parameters should be $elem ($(this)) and $container ($('div.correspondingx'))

Comment: Ok... sorry about that, I'll move it on over

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend jQuery for example so its more reusable:

```
// extend jquery
(function($){

    $.fn.redundantSee = function (subSelector) {

        return this.find('.options').each(function () {
            var self = $(this),
            input = self.find('input'),
            title = self.find('.title').text(),
            value = input.val(),
            source = self.find('img').attr('src'),
            id = input.attr('id'),
            listItem = $('<li/>', { 'value': value, 'id': id }),
            imageElement = $('<img/>', { 'src': source, 'title': title });

            $(subSelector).append(listItem);
            listItem.append(imageElement);
        });

    };

}(jQuery));

// and use it like this
$('.wrapper:eq(0)').redundantSee('div.corresponding1');
$('.wrapper:eq(1)').redundantSee('div.corresponding2');
```

Comment: I'm not going to be able to test this till tomorrow, however, I'm familiar with both extending jQuery and writing reusable functions to accept parameters (which is the way I was thinking of solving this). I'm pretty sure that I'll be able to implement by extending this way. My question for you is, is there any performance benefit of extending jQuery over writing a reusable parameterized function, or is it mostly best practice for chaining and reusability?

Comment: Its more about best practice, I don`t think there are any performance benefits.

Comment: fyi, this works, but just wanted to mention that the first $(this) shouldn't be wrapped in jQuery, and when extending it is advised by the docs to wrap in an iife (http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), and it's also advised to return this for chaining: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.   But otherwise, a very good solution, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I changed the `this` parts, wasnt sure if this was already jQuery and forgot the return, yep, you're right. But I don't see the point for the IIFE as everything is inside the function and should be safe? Feel free to edit my answer and I will accept the changes. Oh and welcome to SO. You should get a name and get addicted, you will be a good addition to the guys here :)

Comment: Cool... I sent the edit in... i forgot to note that you can return 'this' immediately at the top.  The iife is there just in case any other libraries are using the $, so you pass in the $ and invoke it immediately with jQuery.  This is the solution I went with though, and it was a super helpful reminder, so much appreciated.  I'm already hooked!

Comment: Unfortunately your edit has been rejected by three other people before I even see it and I'm no longer able to accept it (I don't understand this review thing - its my answer if somebody edits it it should be ME accepting or rejecting it?). But anyway I was able to see the changes and now I got what you mean with the IIFE because I thought you mean that inside the function. Of course the extension itself should be in an IIFE I was assuming that is given but you're right I  added it. Thanks!

Comment: The only unfortunate thing so far is that I haven't been notified why the rejection occurred.  Don't sweat it... I'm just here to learn stuff, know what i mean?

Comment: Plus, I'm using this code on a client's website, so if there's something really wrong, I'd like to know what it is.  I've followed the docs and advice from included sources.

Comment: I think the reject was just because it changed my code and you are new so nobody had a closer look or even a look at the comments you know? So everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a loop for the wrapper and a loop for the option in each wrapper
And I would use a increment variable for the corresponding DIV.

```
function redundantSee() {
    var i = 0;
    $('.wrapper').each(function(){
        i++;
        $(this).find('.options').each(function(){
            var self = $(this),
                input = self.find('input'),
                title = self.find('.title').text(),
                value = input.val(),
                source = self.find('img').attr('src'),
                id = input.attr('id'),
                listItem = $('<li/>', {'value': value, 'id': id }),
                imageElement = $('<img/>', {'src': source, 'title': title});

            $('div.corresponding' + i).append(nameListItem);
            listItem.append(imageElement);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: The 'div.corresponding' is not something that can just be incremented, because for each one there is a completely different element with a different name... .sorry for the confusion on that.

Comment: @user1798630 if you are using html5 you can attach an data-* attribute on each wrapper to specify the corresponding DIV instead of increment it.

Comment: Actually I can't touch those wrappers... they are generated by a server so I can only manipulate with JavaScript